# How to find and remove duplicate Google+ photos

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

Is there an easy way to find and remove duplicate photos within a Google+ album?

Comment: At the moment it does not seem that Google provides such function. You have to find and remove them manually.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't believe there is a tool built in to Google+ you could use Google's Picasa product to link your account and use it's tools to do this. To do this [download picasa](https://picasa.google.com/) and Link it to your google account (upper right corner).  This should allow you to sync your web based albums, then just follow the below directions:

1. Go to the File Menu -> Import Google+ Photos... and import all your
   google plus Albums. This can take some time depending on your
   connection and the number of files you are downloading.
2. Set the Column to the right of the thumbnails to the Properties
   screen by clicking on the blue circle with a "I" inside in the lower
   right. The Properties Column gives you information about the
   selected photo so you can better choose which ones to keep and which
   to delete. This will also display the unique ID of the photo so you
   should able to compare those to see if they are true dupes as well.
3. Go to the Tools menu -> Options -> General tab. In the General tab
   under Files: make sure the box Delete from Disk Without Confirmation
   is Checked so you won't have to confirm every delete.
4. In the lower right below the thumbnails is the thumbnail size
   slider. Drag it left or right to adjust the thumbnail size for best
   viewing of the duplicates
5. Start the Show Duplicate Files tool: Go to the Tools menu ->
   Experimental -> Show Duplicate Files.

All Folders will be shown that contain Duplicate photos. You should then just have to go through them compare and delete those you feel are dupes.  While this isn't automatic it should help you at least identify those duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all your pictures to a hard disk, run Anti-Twin and delete the duplicates.  Delete all the photos on Google and copy them back again.

Comment: This is not a reasonable option when I have many GBs of data spread across 20,000+ thousands of pictures and movies.

Answer (score -2):

This can be done on Google+. Please try the following:

1. Log into Google Plus
2. Hover over the "Home" menu at the top left of the page, below the google logo
3. Click on photos "should show picasa logo"
4. Place cursor over photo and a check mark bubble will appear and click it, (please note if you are in an album when you hover over a photo to the right of the album date you will see a link called "select" or "select all". Click this to target all photos in album.
5. When photos are all selected click "delete" at top of page, in the blue bar that appears after selecting your photos.

After following those steps you will move all the photos you selected to the trash. You can permanently delete these by going to your trash folder and doing so. **NOTE: there is no way to find duplicates yet. This method however will allow you to select as many as you need at one time.**

[image: Google Plus Photo Delete - Mass Delete]

Comment: Hmm, that's kind-of the important part, finding the duplicates.

Comment: The only logical way to do that is to just brows for the duplication. I have never run across a website that has that type of recognition. But at least I provided you with the answer on how to remove them in bulk! :)